# How to properly add values to StoreQuery for every row in VisitListener in jOOQ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I am trying to set audit fields for each insert or update queries only if a table has audit fields. After lots of trials and errors I came up with this logic using `VisitListener`:

```java
public class AuditVisitListener implements VisitListener {

    private static final Field<Timestamp> createdAt = field("created_at", Timestamp.class);
    private static final Field<String> createdBy = field("created_by", String.class);
    private static final Field<Timestamp> updatedAt = field("updated_at", Timestamp.class);
    private static final Field<String> updatedBy = field("updated_by", String.class);
    private Set<Field<?>> auditFields = new HashSet<>();

    private UserContextHolder userContextHolder;

    public AuditVisitListener(UserContextHolder userContextHolder) {
        this.userContextHolder = userContextHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitStart(VisitContext context) {
        QueryPart topLevelQuery = context.context().topLevel();
        if(topLevelQuery instanceof SelectQuery<?>) {
            // No need to process further since we don't set audit fields for select queries
            return;
        }
        collectAuditFields(context.queryParts());
        if(topLevelQuery instanceof InsertQuery<?> insertQuery) {
            addAuditFieldsForInsert(insertQuery);
        }
        if(topLevelQuery instanceof UpdateQuery<?> updateQuery) {
            addAuditFieldsForUpdate(updateQuery);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visitEnd(VisitContext context) {
        // Without this line, audit fields are added
        // even if there is no audit fields in a table. 
        auditFields.clear();
    }

    private void collectAuditFields(QueryPart[] queryParts) {
        for(QueryPart queryPart : queryParts) {
           if(queryPart instanceof Table<?> table) {
               if(table.field(createdAt) != null){
                   auditFields.add(createdAt);
               }
               if(table.field(createdBy) != null) {
                  auditFields.add(createdBy);
               }
               if(table.field(updatedAt) != null) {
                  auditFields.add(updatedAt);
               }
               if(table.field(updatedBy) != null) {
                   auditFields.add(updatedBy);
               }
           }
        }
    }

    private void addAuditFieldsForInsert(StoreQuery<?> storeQuery) {
        if(auditFields.contains(createdAt)) {
            storeQuery.addValue(createdAt, now());
        }
        if(auditFields.contains(createdBy)) {
            storeQuery.addValue(createdBy, userId());
        }
        addAuditFieldsForUpdate(storeQuery);
    }

    private void addAuditFieldsForUpdate(StoreQuery<?> storeQuery) {
        if(auditFields.contains(updatedAt)) {
            storeQuery.addValue(updatedAt, now());
        }
        if(auditFields.contains(updatedBy)) {
            storeQuery.addValue(updatedBy, userId());
        }
    }

    private String userId() {
        return userContextHolder.getUserId()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BusinessException(ErrorCode.EMPTY_USER_CONTEXT));
    }

}
```

First problem is without `auditFields.clear()`, audit fields are added even if there is no audit fields in a table. Why does it happen?
Second problem is it works for single row inserts but when insert statement has multiple rows it sets audit fields only to the last row. For example this insert statement:

```java
    ctx.insertInto(BRAND, BRAND.NAME_EN, BRAND.NAME_KR, BRAND.STATUS)
            .values("Heinz", "하인즈", (short)1)
            .values("Hunts", "헌츠", (short)1)
            .execute();
```

produces this query:

```sql
insert into `pms`.`brand` (`name_en`, `name_kr`, `status`, created_at, created_by, updated_at, updated_by) 
values ('Heinz', '하인즈', 1, null, null, null, null),
       ('Hunts', '헌츠', 1, current_timestamp(), 'test@test.com', current_timestamp(), 'test@test.com')
```

However, if I insert multiple rows a batch insert it again works:

```java
    BrandRecord heinz = ctx.newRecord(BRAND);
    heinz.setNameEn("Heinz");
    heinz.setNameKr("하인즈");
    heinz.setStatus((short)1);

    BrandRecord hunts = ctx.newRecord(BRAND);
    hunts.setNameEn("Hunts");
    hunts.setNameKr("헌츠");
    hunts.setStatus((short)1);

    ctx.batchInsert(heinz, hunts).execute();
```

How to set audit fields for multirow insert or update statements?

For reference, `AuditVisitListener` is configured using `VisitListenerProvider`:

```java
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultConfigurationCustomizer customizer(UserContextHolder userContextHolder) {
        return configuration -> {
            configuration.setVisitListenerProvider(() -> new AuditVisitListener(userContextHolder));
        };
    }

}
```

jOOQ: 3.18 
Java: 17 
Spring Boot: 3.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is `auditFields.clear()` necessary

This points to a bigger problem in your design. The lifecycle of your `VisitListener` probably isn't per query rendering, but per `Configuration`, meaning your various queries share the same instance. This means that `clear()` seems to "fix" the issue, but in fact hides a much bigger concurrency problem.

Either, you should use a `VisitListenerProvider` that instantiates new `VisitListener` instances every time, or put your context in the `VisitContext`, instead, whose lifecycle is that of a single rendering traversal.

#### Why does it only work on the last row

The (very historic) `InsertQuery` and `UpdateQuery` APIs only allow for appending data to the last row. To add a new row, `InsertQuery.newRecord()` is called. From then on, there's no public API in `InsertQuery` to append values to previous rows.

This isn't the case for batch queries, which are multiple queries, not multiple rows per query.

The newer (as of jOOQ 3.18 still experimental) [model API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/) will allow you to access all the rows in the `VALUES` clause. It will also allow for writing much simpler SQL transformation logic that doesn't need the `VisitListener` SPI.

#### A note on alternatives

Please note that jOOQ has:

- An [out of the box audit column feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-audit/) for simple audit use-cases
- [Client side computed column support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-computed/) for more complex computed column use-cases

It will be *much* easier to just work with that, or, alternatively, use a trigger to fill those column values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  About `VisitListenerProvider`, isn't this line already doing what you are suggesting: `configuration.setVisitListenerProvider(() -> new AuditVisitListener(userContextHolder));`

Comment: @ElyorbekIbrokhimov: You're right, I missed that bit. Then, I'm not sure why the `clear()` call is necessary, without debugging it. Have you tried that? You could set a breakpoint on all accesses to your `auditFields` set

Comment: I found the reason. There was another jOOQ configuration only for tests which did't use `VisitListenerProvider` instead just used `setVisitListener()`. That's why tests were failing. Thanks again for the amazing work!

Comment: @ElyorbekIbrokhimov: Ah, so my intuition was right, after all :)